# Enabling authorization in mongod.cfg makes server crash

Tags: mongodb, authorization, roles

I am trying to enable mongodb authorization on my local machine (windows 10) I do this by adding the following settings in my mongod.cfg file.

```
#security:
authorization: "enabled"
```

When I do this and try to restart mongodb server as service on windows, it crashes with this messages, windows could not start mongodb server.

I tried to start mongodb service through terminal, with following command.
net start Mongodb.
this also gives and error, with message access is denied.

NOTE: without adding authorization configuration in monogd.cfg file, server works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It must be this (without hashtag and with spaces) :

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```